# Url optional parameter regular expression

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a routing controller that accepts a route with parameters like so:

`/news/:id`

and i get the id with this regular expression:

`:([\w]+)`

However the parameter can be optional with this syntax:

`/users/[:id]`

How do I modify the regular expression to capture both cases?

Comment: What is the actual use case here? Why are you parsing this route placeholder with a regex?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/M5wELN/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex: `(?:\:[\w]+|\[\:\w+\])`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M5wELN/5)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an a/b problem, but this will work for what you've asked:

```
\[?\w+]?
```

Assuming your route placeholders are only lower case numbers and digits.
Of course it would change if you provided more detail on the structure of your placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to escape the `\]` `\:`, the non capture group `(?:` and the single word character in the character class `[\w]+`

The pattern can be:

```
:\w+|\[:\w+]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XMSvhz/1)